# Installing pfsense on Company Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, pfsense

I would greatly appreciate some tips and advice on how I can replace my company Router with pfsense. I will explain the network infrastructure shortly.

The Network Setup is as follows

ISP connects to > Router connects to > Proxy Server connects to > Distribution Switch

The Router is given a static IP from the ISP (197.x.x.x) and is assigned a static local IP address (10.136.69.235).

Now the part that confuses me. The DHCP Server is turned off on the router, NAT is enabled. A static route is configured to: Destination IP address (10.136.69.0) subnet (255.255.255.0) Gateway (10.136.69.1) Interface (Internet).

We get our Active Directory/Domain Controller from a provider, and their DNS/DHCP is 10.128.2.11/10.128.2.13. I believe that they are providing us with IP addresses since the DHCP is turned off on our router. This is what confuses me.

I want to improve the network appliances by installing and configuring pfsense to similar settings.

I am confused whether is should just put the current router in bridged mode and connect pfsense to it and configure it like our router was, i am sort off lost.

Any tips would be helpful, or if you understand what i have explained above.

Comment: What device does the 10.136.69.1 address belong to? And what does "Proxy Server" do in all of this? Is it like a router, a transparent proxy of some sort, or a real proxy server with no IP-level forwarding that everyone manually configures in their browsers? It's sitting right in the middle of your network, so it's probably the massive missing piece here.

Comment: not sure what the 10.136.69.1 address belongs to, it is just set as a static route default gateway in the router config. The proxy server is setup to filter internet traffic from the local network before going through the router, the NIC that connects to the router and NIC that connects to the distribution switch are bridged together. And yes you are correct the users have pre-configured proxy settings in their browser in order to get internet access. The proxy address is 10.136.69.155, default gateway is the router's IP (10.136.69.235) and DNS is 8.8.8.8, so order to get internet connectivity